# Returning File Line Position from Randomly Selected Line

Tags: python, file

I'm pulling random lines from a small file (11 lines or less) and I would like to return the line position to a variable.

Better yet if I can use randrange to determin the line number that would make the data manipulation far easier.

The top 3 and bottom 3 values I am trying to apply a percentage chance to display a different string otherwise show what is in the line of the file.

```
            elif data.GetParam(1)== "common":
                def check(w, select):
                    return(all(x == select for x in w))
                    
                i = random.randrange(1,100)
                w = [0,1,2,8,9,10]
                select = random.randrange(0,10)
                list = []
                
                if (check(w, select)):
                    #if (i > 74):
                        list[0] = str(random.randrange(1,4))
                        list[1] = "reduced points"

                else:
                    biome = open('common.txt').read().splitlines()              #get random string from file


                    for line in biome:
                        list = line.split(";") #separate string into a list
                    
                    if list[0] == '1':                                                                      #check first list item and replace with applicable value
                        list[0] = str(random.randrange(1,4))
                    else:
                        list[0] = ''
```

currently I have it able to read the file and it is always displaying the first line no matter what.

I realized after a comment that I was missing some info I had intended to put.
Here's the lines in the common.txt file

```
1; Mandrake Root;
1; Quicksilver Lichen;
1; Quicksilver Lichen;
1; Wild Sageroot;
1; Wild Sageroot;
1; Bloodgrass;
1; Wyrmtongue Petals;
1; Wyrmtongue Petals;
1; Milkweed Seeds;
1; Milkweed Seeds;
1; Mandrake Root;
```

As for line positon I mean if it randomly selects line 5 I would either like to return that number and place it in a variable or generate that number using say randrange(0,10) if that makes sense.

The output code is as follows

```
m_Response = data.User + ", you find... " + list[0] + list[1] + "."
```

in text it should look like this

```
(username), you find... (1-4)(ItemName).
```

the 1-4 is based off of the first value in a line (there will be other numbers placed here eventually.

ItemName is based off of the second value in a line.

Comment: It would be a lot clearer if you gave an example of what the input file might contains and some example output in that case. And by "line position", are you talking about byte offset or line number? Again, an example would clarify.

Comment: edited the original post. thanks for pointing out I missed the file data

Comment: Thank you for adding example input. Please also give example output.

Comment: made the changes I hope the aditons were clear

Comment: I ended up adding a number 0-10 at the beginning of each line in the file I'm selecting from and compared it to my w range.

Also had to change the w range to string values instead of numbers.